# android app not responding with using thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I implemented a program that have a UI. In UI I have 2 button (start and finish). When I clicked start button my service in my app run, and with finish button my service finished.
In my service I connected to xmpp server, when speed of internet is high I don't have any problem, but when speed of internet is low, it takes a long time to connect `xmpp server` and my UI don't do any thing and crashed. I put connecting to xmpp server in a thread.

my code is:

```
public class FirstAct  extends Activity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    btnStart.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        startService(new Intent(act, MainActivity.class));
    }});

    btnEnd.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick( View v ) {
        stopService(new Intent(act, MainActivity.class));
    }});
  }
}
```

//------------------------

```
public class MainService extends Service {

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    ....
    toastHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    ....
  }

  private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler() {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "null","unused" })
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
      try{
        connectToXmppServer();
        }catch(Exception e){    
      }
    }
  };
```

what should I do that, when ConnectToXMPP takes a long time, all of program not crashed???

please help me

Comment: have you define service in manifest ?

Comment: my service is ok,it runs perfectly, I don't have any problem with service

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends Service`. Why are you naming a service as MainActivity? Please do not do such confusing things.

Comment: why  ConnectToXMPP function is in thread but when it not work all of app not work?

Comment: share you error logcat

Comment: `, I put connecting to xmpp server in a thread .`. Where is the thread?

Comment: Handler toastHandler = new Handler() : it is thread.isn't it?

Comment: I don't know alot about Handler()

Comment: `my service is ok,it runs perfectly, I don't have any problem with service`. ???? Then why this post?

Comment: my service start and stop fine, but when ConnectToXMPP function ,not works well(because of speed of internet), all of app crashed, I want when this function crashed , all of  app not stop:(

Comment: I THINK MY THREAD NOT WORK WELL

Comment: my app not responding, not stop working , excuse me

Comment: I think your service is far from perfect. You are complaining about a function but are not showing the code for it. So what do you think we can do?

Comment: I think that function is not important , it is important that this function is in thread even if that not work well , all of app and UI should not be unusable and not responding.

Comment: in fact I want a parallel thread that works perfect

Comment: put your App crash Log here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this thread instead of `Handler`:

```
void runInBackground() {
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      connectToXmppServer();
    }
  }).start();
}
```